# JSTL fmt formatDate tag is passed as it is instead of the desired value

Tags: jsp, jstl, formatdatetime

I am assigning the formatted date to an `<form:input>` tag but instead of the formatted date, the jstl code is allocated to the textfield.

```
<form:input path="DOB" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' value='${editableUser.DOB}'/>" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${editableUser.DOB}" var="myDateVar"/>
<form:input path="DOB" value="${myDateVar}"/>
```

Tested and Working.